# Возможно ли через css скрыть часть символа за рисунком?

Tags: css, css3

Доброго времени суток. 
Возможно ли через css скрыть часть символа за рисунком , если рисунок вставлен фоном?
Как тут к примеру.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что мешает вставить рисунок НЕ фоном?) Можно ведь вырезать планету отдельно и наложить сверху, например

Comment: Или вообще текст прописать на изображении, чтобы меньше мучиться в позиционировании при адаптивной верстке.

Comment: @Игорь-Мясников весь проект на stackoverflow частями закинуть со скринами, без строчки кода круто конечно)) вы хотябы свои попытки добавляйте, или всё должны сделать за вас?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
background:url(http://www.fainaidea.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/oboi-kosmos-1366x768.jpg);
background-size:cover;
}
.textonimage {
  position:absolute;
  
}
.textonimage img {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:-100px
}
.textonimage span {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:4em;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="textonimage">
<span>
Путешествие <br> на <br> солнце
</span>
<img src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/57286345dc4fe15475c3c90e.png" width="200">
</div>
```